# Remove border around NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsoutlineview

When I add a NSOutlineView to my NSWindow, it has a visible border around it although I set a constraint to 0 spacing.

[image]

How can I remove this border? (I assume that it can be removed as in Finder for example this border does not exist)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the outline view in IB or in code?

Comment: Did the outline view in IB

Comment: Snap the sides of the outline view to its sides of the superview and add constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I’ve done in the past is just set the constraints to -1.